# Qt:: Drag And Drop Image

Tags: qt

I am Creating App. that contains Picture Editing. i have take two QLabel And set image on each of Qlabel. now i want to Drag one image and put it on other Image..
how can i do that?
Any help?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Graphic View Framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/graphicsview.html) with [QGraphicsPixmapItem](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicspixmapitem.html) could solve your problem.